# android:autoLink="web" in java

Tags: android, autolink

how to set `android:autoLink="web"` that can be set inside XML inside the class, for example for this textView

```
final TextView finalTv;
finalTv.setMovementMethod(testCase);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the Android documentation, you should use TextView's `setAutoLinkMask` (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setAutoLinkMask(int)), passing in one of these enums:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html#ALL

For web, you would probably want to use this value:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html#WEB_URLS

Comment: thank you so much I was not found any info about the enums to use the method